# Child objects don't move with parent

Tags: parent

So, i used Archimesh addon, to create curtains, but they have been created in the wrong collection.
[image: Venetian Frame is the object i am trying to move]

But when i try to move it into the another collection, every child inside of a Venetian Frame stays in a Lighting collection.

[image: oof]

Any ways to fix that? I can't select every single one of them, since those objects are parents too.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way it works, children won't follow their parent unless you select them, what you can do is right click on the parent and choose > *Select Hierarchy*, then move to the collection you want.

Comment: HE IS THE MESSIAH! Thank you very much!